# Confused about navigation UP vs BACK on Andorid

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

Designer here. I have a question about reverse navigation in Android OS.

My question is, in the scenario here
[link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMjD3.png)
The app's home page has a direct access to a certain content (level 3) within a module (level 2).

The user tap on that content from the homepage. In this case, how should the UP navigation behaves? (The two red lines)

1. Should it bring the user UP to the level 2 Module B page?  (Which is one level up based on the app hierarchy)
   OR
2. Should it bring the user back to homepage? (Which is the last place they were at)

========

From my understanding (and years of using Android phones), the UP navigation (from Top app bar) is always navigate the user one level up within the app hierarchy.   the BACK navigation (system back button/gesture) is navigate chronologically back to where the user were.  (In general)

(Ref: https://m2.material.io/design/navigation/understanding-navigation.html#reverse-navigation)

But based on this page: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#up_and_back_are_identical_within_your_apps_task
"Within your app's task, the Up and Back buttons behave identically." which means that the UP button should direct the user back to the homepage, not level 2. (? I'm very confused... )

Is this a relatively new change for Android dev?

Which Red line is the correct behavior?  Thank you  :)

I checked two guidelines from Google,and they seem contradict with each other

https://m2.material.io/design/navigation/understanding-navigation.html#reverse-navigation

and

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#up_and_back_are_identical_within_your_apps_task

Comment: The entire Material 2 site has been deprecated for some time. Why are you looking at that page at all?

Comment: They don't have an updated page on Navigation on the Material 3 site. And Material 3 is only released 2 years ago. not that long